# Resolving CONNECT ERROR in magento connect manager

Tags: magento2, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

I am getting the following Error while installing a package in magento using "Magento Connect Manager" :

> **Checking dependencies of packages**
>
> **CONNECT ERROR: Failed to open file var/package/tmp/package.xml**

I have tried removing **connect.cfg** and **cache.cfg** from the downloader folder. Tried refreshing and login out. Infact I tried almost everything. But still the same problem.

I am stuck on this problem for hours, not able to do install any package.

Comment: you can try by installing files through ftp.

Comment: did you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....